# flv file loses quality when uploaded to server

Tags: flash-cs4, flv

When i view an flv file inside a swf file it looks fine locally, but when its uploaded text loses it shape. The bitrate for the flv is 1,500+ kbps. Ive attached a picture. The one on the left is local, and the one on the right is over the web. Anyone know what might be happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give some detail on the authoring tools you use and the server you download to. It's difficult to answer your question without some details.

Some raw guesses:

- when you watch locally your flv, it could not be encoded yet but some kind of preview
- the server you download to may use some stream transcoder and not send directly your file
- for some reason the stage size when you play from the server is smaller than when played locally. (if so [this thread](http://www.justskins.com/forums/loadmovie-and-finding-the-width-and-height-83567.html) could be of some help)

Comment: when i resize the window the web version is on, the text quality inside the flv changes. Im thinking the stage size is causing it. If so, is there a way to fix the stage size?

Comment: You may be right, from your picture movie could be slightly streched down and yscale smaller than 100%. Still not enough details to be positive on anything.

Comment: ok. I use flash cs4 professional. I encoded the flv in adobe media encoder cs4, using on2 vp6 codec. The file size is 4mb.

Comment: The y-scale does look shorter.  Question: How are you sending FLV to client?  HTTP?  Or?